# Asus Memopad sd card unexpected removed

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

At the moment the Asus Memopad HD7 came out, i bought it.

I bought also a micro sd card and inserted it. But frequently the sd card will be unexpected removed.

Is there anyone who recognizes this? Is it a general problem with the Memopad?

Comment: Never heard about such, but I also never used the Memopad. As a precaution, you might want to check all the apps you've installed for those having the permission to mount/unmount file systems, maybe one of them has gone havoc.

Comment: I will go to the shop where i bought it and get another one. Maybe it is a production failure

Comment: That might be possible, yes. Please update us concerning the results then :)

Answer (score 1):

My wife is having the same issue.  It seems to be related to how you hold or handle the tablet.  If she hands it to me and I am handling it by the top right corner, it will almost always sense the card is not there.  As soon as I change where I am holding it by the card is mounted again.  It seems like the card is loosing contact with the port by a minor flexing (just by the weight of the tablet itself) when you handle the top right corner only.  It is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem….. downloading the firmware update from ASUS (from the HD7 tablet) appear to have solved the problems.  Remember, you must un-mount the Micro sd Before removing it……………… see manual http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeePAD/ME173X/e8255_k00B_me173X_em.pdf

Good Luck

Good Luck

Comment: i have updated my firmware, but the sd card still removes unexpectedly. (although it seems to be less sensitive.) I am going to go to the shop where i bought it. I will update this soon.